# staccato-rails - can't figure out geo tracking on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm finding that most of my visitors have ad block / ghostery... so I'm trying to implement server side tracking with google analytics using staccato-rails. 
https://github.com/tpitale/staccato-rails
https://github.com/tpitale/staccato/

I have it working pretty well so far, but when on heroku, all visitors on the server side are showing up from Ashburn Va. Development seems to be working as it should...

My guess is that this is a request.remote_ip vs request.env['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] problem... but I've been logging both, and both seem to be giving the correct ip address in my logs...

I've read through the docs a few times... and still can't figure it out...

my latest attempt:

```
tracker.pageview(
    user_ip: request.env['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'], 
    user_agent: request.env["HTTP_USER_AGENT"], 
    path: "path", 
    title: "Title"
)
```

which seems to be having the same problem... any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!